# System.NullReferenceException was unhandled ERROR

Tags: c#

```js
int danoAoInimigo = GeradorDeNumeroAleatorio.NumeroEntre(0, 10);
int danoAoJogador = GeradorDeNumeroAleatorio.NumeroEntre(0, 10);
Console.WriteLine(">>PRESSIONE QUALQUER TECLA<<");
Console.ReadKey();
Console.WriteLine("Você causou: " + danoAoInimigo + " de dano ao"   _jogador.LocalAtual.InimigoVivendoAqui.Nome + " !! "); 

_jogador.LocalAtual.InimigoVivendoAqui.VidaAtual = (_jogador.LocalAtual.InimigoVivendoAqui.VidaAtual) - danoAoInimigo;


Console.WriteLine("O inimigo tem: " + _jogador.LocalAtual.InimigoVivendoAqui.VidaAtual + " de vida.");
if (_jogador.LocalAtual.InimigoVivendoAqui.VidaAtual <= 0)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Você matou o inimigo.");
   Console.WriteLine(">>PRESSIONE QUALQUER TECLA<<");
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Basically What I'm doing here is just a simple "battle system" for my text game. It starts with the declaration of two variables to hold the damage that the palyer will dealt to the monster and the damage that the monster will dealt to the player. And then I made a message to the user for he knows how much damage he dealts. And then I made the monster lose life with some classes that I'm using and after i'm displaying the current life of the monster to the user. And finally if the health of the monster is less or equal to 0 he dies.

The problem is: everytime I run de code and get at this part of the game, the visual studio gives me a message in a little window saying that "System.NullReferenceException was unhandled". But I already have two more parts of the code before this one where I have those same lines and it had never show me this problem and it works perfectly.
So could someone help me with this one? I really have no idea what to do.

Comment: With your posted code i cannot indicate where there should be an error. Can you please post the exception and the line causing this error?

Comment: Sure! I don't anything about an exception but the line is this one where I show to the user the amount of damage he dealts "Console.WriteLine("Você causou: " + danoAoInimigo + " de dano ao"   _jogador.LocalAtual.InimigoVivendoAqui.Nome + " !! ")";

Comment: sorry about the strings and the variables names. I'm not from US so I wrote things like this in Portuguese.

Answer (score 0):

Im surprised that you can even compile!

You are missing a *+* here

```
Console.WriteLine("Você causou: " + danoAoInimigo + " de dano ao"   _jogador.LocalAtual.InimigoVivendoAqui.Nome + " !! ");
```

**Change it to**

```
Console.WriteLine("Você causou: " + danoAoInimigo + " de dano ao" +  _jogador.LocalAtual.InimigoVivendoAqui.Nome + " !! ");
```

EDIT:

In that case, probably your `_jogador.LocalAtual.InimigoVivendoAqui.Nome` is null. Be sure you set this variable at least to `""`

Comment: No it isn't the problem, I just miss it when I was passing the code to the question blanke. Sorry.